# Error page based on host

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.6

With Symfony2, it's easy to match routes based on the host (details here http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html).

I would like to have different error pages according to host.

404 error on example.com -> one layout
404 error on test.com -> another layout

How would you do that ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the configuration of your webservers, you could declare the template name as an environment variable which Symfony can pick up and use as application parameter.

Example:
configure the following ENV in Apache, for the first (virtual)host:

```
SetEnv SYMFONY__ERROR_TEMPLATE SomeBundle:error:template1.html.twig
```

... and for the second:

```
SetEnv SYMFONY__ERROR_TEMPLATE SomeBundle:error:template2.html.twig
```

Then you can inject that parameter to whatever service you use to render your error page (most likely an exception listener):

```
# Your exception listener
your_exception_listener:
    class:     SomeClass
    arguments:
        - @dependency1
        - ...
        - %error_template%
```

You can then simply render the template passed as a parameter and remove any hardcoded template reference in code.

This way, by running the same code in both hosts, you can display two different layouts for error pages.

NOTE: You'll also have to remember setting an environment variable with the same name in your shell, or you will get exceptions when the app runs in CLI mode.

More information here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html